# Reasoning for downvotes and close votes on a question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, down-votes

I have asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21357984/algorithms-to-solve-a-rubiks-cube) on SO, and it has accumulated 5 downvotes in as many minutes. I am not going to say that I am infallible, but I do not see the reasoning behind so many downvotes in such a small timeframe. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

I am asking a question, not on how to solve the Rubik's cube, but what steps would be appropriate in creating a program to solve a Rubik's cube with the use of algorithms.

I haven't been on in a few months, so this may be something new or something old I am just overlooking. Either way, I would like to know what I have done wrong.

**EDIT:** I have revised the question, could someone tell me if I did a good job or not?

Comment: Skimming the question; the close reason itself stems from "Are there any source code examples or any pointers that I could get for this project?" SO isn't the place to look for outside examples. Even if you wanted to stick to just pointers; it's hard to not have the resulting question be too broad.

Comment: @DennisMeng I see what you are saying, and I agree. Is there a way I can tweak the question to improve it, or am I better off just deleting it and completely rewriting it?

Comment: I'm not sure how well you can rewrite that question to make it work. Like I said; after you remove the part asking for outside stuff, it's hard to make that not be too broad. My vote would be to delete the question, and ask a different one *when you've narrowed your problem down to a more specific issue.* "How do I approach this?" for this kind of thing is doomed to be too broad, whereas "I'm trying to do X, but am stuck on this small piece" has a chance of being okay.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your question basically boils down to "do my work for me".  I realize that might not have been your intention, but when you say "what's the code to do x" (and here `code = algorithm`) without providing any indication that you did prior research or made an attempt yourself, you are coming across as asking for other users to do your research for you.

If you had indicated what you had tried, you might have staved off most of the downvotes.  Likewise, the one phrase most that directly resulted in the question getting closed was:

> Are there any source code examples or any pointers that I could get for this project?

Questions just asking for resources are off-topic, so people interpreted that as you seeking nothing but a link to another site.

Comment: OK. I see what you are saying, and see that I worded the question poorly. Would it be better to edit the question, or to just completely rewrite it?

Comment: @Grammar almost always edit.  Thye only time you don't want to edit is when you have existing answers that would be invalidated by your edit.